# coffeescript indentations with loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following js.coffee / Coffeescript where I want to get the market data as output:

```
window.MarketsUI = flight.component ->
  @defaultAttrs
    table: 'tbody'
    filter: '.dropdown-menu a'

  @refresh = (data) ->
    $table = @select('table')
   $table.prepend(JST['market'](market)) for market in data.markets
   console.log data.markets

  @filter = (event) ->
    type = event.target.className
    return @list.filter() if type == ''

    @list.filter (item) ->
      item.values().type == "#{gon.i18n[type]}"

  @initList = ->
    options =
      valueNames: [ 'market', 'currency', 'vol', 'change',
      'last', 'high', 'low']
    @list = new List('marketsX', options)

  @after 'initialize', ->

    markets = []
    $.getJSON "/api/v2/tickers", (data) ->
     #markets = []
     for cur of data
       ticker = data[cur].ticker
       item = {}
       [
         "change"
         "last"
         "high"
         "low"
       ].forEach (key) ->
         item[key] = ticker[key]
         return

       item.volume = ticker.vol
       item.market = cur
       item.currency = cur.substring(3)
       markets.push item
       console.log markets

   markets.sort (a, b)->
     a.volume - b.volume

   @refresh {markets: markets}

   @initList()

   @on @select('filter'), 'click', @filter
```

my problem is that the markets object is empty when I console log it in the @refresh function. I get only []. I know it has something to do with the indentations of coffeescript since its working in pure JS. It is also working when I hardcore the markets data.

Comment: Can you provide a small self-contained example? There's a lot of code there that doesn't have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an obvious (at least when you have a look at the compiled JS) indentation problem:

> ```
>   @refresh = (data) ->
>     $table = @select('table')
>    $table.prepend(JST['market'](market)) for market in data.markets
>    console.log data.markets
> ```

It needs to be

```
  @refresh = (data) ->
    $table = @select('table')
    $table.prepend(JST['market'](market)) for market in data.markets
    console.log data.markets
#  ^
```

Also, it looks like the `markets.sort`, `@refresh` and `@initlist` calls need to go in the ajax callback, but I'm not sure what you want (and you haven't told us).

Comment: thank you. That was an obvious problem which i did not see. Also I moved the rest into the ajax callback. Now I get however the error TypeError: undefined is not a function for this.refresh

Comment: When accessing methods (or anything on `this`/`@`) you need to use `=>` for the callback instead of `->`.